# Use polyroot() or looking for other ways to compute the P[real roots]

Tags: r

Suppose that A,B, and C are independent random variables, each being uniformly distributed over (0,1). 
What is the probability that `AX^2+BX+C` has real roots?

I found that the probability is .2544.

How to verify that the answer you have is correct by using R? Will the command [`polyroot()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/polyroot.html) in R be useful in determining this?

Will you have to write a program to compute the P[real roots]? I am told "Using `polyroot()` will require 40 times as much CPU time than a more direct method suggested by your analytical solution to this problem, which is `(5+6log(2))/36)`.

Moreover, unless you are adroit with floating point arithmetic, you will obtain a (subtly) incorrect result. Note that no amount of such computation in R can actually "verify" such a mathematical result; it can only corroborate it--that is, you hope the code output and the math will not contradict one another. "

If that is the case, is there more efficient to achieve this result?

Comment: why do you need polyroot? just check the discriminant.

Comment: In fact, there's a theorem (which I can't remember after all these years) which gives you all possible numbers of real and imaginary roots of any polynomial, based on the count of sign changes in the coefficients.  It should be no surprise that, for all-real coefficients, imaginary roots come in pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't need polyroot, just check the discriminant.

```
mean(replicate(100000, {
    coef = runif(3)  
    delta = coef[2]^2 - 4*coef[1]*coef[3] # b^2 - 4ac
    delta>0
}))
```

if you insist to use polyroot

```
mean(replicate(100000, {
    coef = runif(3)  
    roots = polyroot(coef)
    all.equal(Im(roots),c(0,0))==TRUE
}))
```

The first method took 0.688s and the second one took 9.923s on my computer

Comment: If I use polyroot(), I am wondering what the command will be. Could you show me that as well?

Comment: just want to understand why they are different in terms of the running time...what take the second set of commands take that much longer?

Comment: in the second approach, extra time is spent to calculate the exact roots and it is not necessary since the discriminant can already indicate if the roots are real.

Comment: also... can you comment on what does "all.equal(Im(roots),c(0,0))==TRUE" mean?

Comment: Im(roots) returns the imaginary parts of the roots and this command check if the roots have 0 imaginary part, i.e., if they are real or not.

Comment: compare the imaginary parts to zeros